# highcharts getjson: why a "?" in callbackname?

Tags: jquery, callback, highcharts

I'm newbie on jquery, highchart etc...

Why is there a callback with a "?" as parameter in the following code:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?',   function(data) {
seriesOptions[i] = {
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)

I don't understand the meaning of "?" ? why not simply use a clear name such as "callback_name" or "johndoe" ?

Can I replace this by:

```
url = 'sonde_exp_json.php?sonde_id=' + name + '&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function (json_data) {
....
```

Comment: Please read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` on the end of the URL tells jQuery that it is a **JSONP** request instead of **JSON**.

The request is being made to `http://www.highcharts.com/` which is a cross domain request.

And it has to be handled using `jsonp`

Comment: Also, `?` will be replaced with the callbackname generated by jQuery, or the one that you give it if you specified a jsonpcallback option.

Comment: should I use JSONP to get JSON data from the same IP machine ? I presume JSON is enough ? In that case, should I add a readable callback name ?

Comment: If it is from the same domain, then you can just use `json` and the callback is not reuqired

Comment: @Kevin @ Sushanth: you make my day. it was unclear for me in the doc. Tx !

Comment: @ThomasP.. Glad I could be of help :)